# Altering column data type

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

How can I alter a column of number to a list of numbers.

In myTable, m_no is an integer. Now I wish to change m_no column to a list of integers without loosing the currently stored values.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    m_id,
    m_no
);
```

Comment: Storing a list of values in a string column isn't a good idea; it makes it much harder to handle and validate the data. You could have a column that is a collection of numbers, but that still isn't ideal. One row per value is better - if not in this table (if theer are other columns or you need `m_id` to be a PK) then move `m_no` out to a new table with a FK for `m_id`.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to store a list of numbers in a column (especially not as comma-separated values).

What you should do is create another table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    m_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE myTable_numbers (
    m_id REFERENCES mytable(m_id),
    m_no NUMBER(10,0)
);
```

Then, when you want to get the list of numbers for an id you can use a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT mt.m_id,
       mtn.m_no
FROM   mytable mt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable_numbers mtn
       ON (mt.m_id = mtn.m_id)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT ALL
  INTO myTable (m_id) VALUES (1)
  INTO myTable (m_id) VALUES (2)
  INTO myTable (m_id) VALUES (3)
  INTO myTable_numbers (m_id, m_no) VALUES (1, 1)
  INTO myTable_numbers (m_id, m_no) VALUES (1, 2)
  INTO myTable_numbers (m_id, m_no) VALUES (1, 3)
  INTO myTable_numbers (m_id, m_no) VALUES (3, 2)
  INTO myTable_numbers (m_id, m_no) VALUES (3, 4)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| M_ID | M_NO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | *null* |

Or, if you want a comma-separated list of numbers (for display purposes) then `JOIN` and aggregate:

```sql
SELECT mt.m_id,
       LISTAGG(mtn.m_no, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY mtn.m_no) AS m_nos
FROM   mytable mt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable_numbers mtn
       ON (mt.m_id = mtn.m_id)
GROUP BY mt.m_id;
```

Which outputs:

| M_ID | M_NOS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | *null* |
| 3 | 2,4 |

---

If you want to modify the existing table to use two tables then:

1. Create the `myTable_numbers` table using the DDL statement above (without the referential constraint).
2. Copy the data using `INSERT INTO mytable_numbers (m_id, m_no) SELECT m_id, m_no FROM my_table;`
3. Drop the `m_no` column from `mytable`.
4. Delete the duplicate `m_id` values from `myTable`.
5. Add a primary key or unique constraint on `mytable.m_id`.
6. Add the referential constraint on `mytable_numbers.m_id` to `mytable.m_id`.

---

If you really want a list of numbers in a column (don't) then use a nested table:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10,0);

CREATE TABLE myTable (
  m_id  NUMBER,
  m_nos int_list
)
STORE m_nos AS mytable_numbers;
```

Then you can insert the same data:

```sql
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (m_id, m_nos) VALUES (1, int_list(1,2,3))
  INTO mytable (m_id, m_nos) VALUES (2, int_list())
  INTO mytable (m_id, m_nos) VALUES (3, int_list(2,4))
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

And use the queries:

```sql
SELECT mt.m_id,
       mtn.COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   mytable mt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE(mt.m_nos) mtn
       ON 1 = 1;
```

or

```sql
SELECT mt.m_id,
       LISTAGG(mtn.COLUMN_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY mtn.COLUMN_VALUE)
         AS m_nos
FROM   mytable mt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE(mt.m_nos) mtn
       ON 1 = 1
GROUP BY mt.m_id;
```

giving the same output as above.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rv2nlEJX)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a straightforward task as you can't change column's datatype if that column isn't empty (and yours isn't).

Moreover, it depends on what you call a "list of integers"; a simple option is if it represents a string with comma-separated integer values. Basically, a `varchar2` datatype column. Or, did you mean to use a nested table?

Presuming it is a simple *string*, here's a walkthrough:

Original table with some values:

```
SQL> create table mytable (m_id number, m_no number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into mytable values (1, 100);

1 row created.
```

If you just try to change `m_no` column's datatype, it won't work:

```
SQL> alter table mytable modify m_no varchar2(50);
alter table mytable modify m_no varchar2(50)
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype
```

Therefore, add a new column (to store "original" value):

```
SQL> alter table mytable add m_no_old number;

Table altered.

SQL> update mytable set m_no_old = m_no;

1 row updated.
```

Empty the original column:

```
SQL> update mytable set m_no = null;

1 row updated.
```

Change its datatype:

```
SQL> alter table mytable modify m_no varchar2(50);

Table altered.
```

Move original values back:

```
SQL> update mytable set m_no = m_no_old;

1 row updated.
```

Drop newly added column:

```
SQL> alter table mytable drop column m_no_old;

Table altered.
```

Add some more *integers* into it:

```
SQL> update mytable set m_no = m_no || ', 200, 300';

1 row updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from mytable;

      M_ID M_NO
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 100, 200, 300
```